# Can I use LSTM for non-sequential data like using FFNN when LSTM shows much better performance?

Tags: deep-learning, regression, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, nonsequential

Task:
I'm working on a regression task using deep learning models.

Data:
I have a tabular dataset with approximately 1 million rows. Each row contains 59 features and a dependent variable. It's NOT sequential data, like time series or natural language data.

What I've tried:
I know that a feedforward neural network (FFNN) is typically suitable for my task. Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) or Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) networks are usually used for sequential data.

Despite this, I tried using an LSTM model on my non-sequential data, similar to how I'd use an FFNN. The LSTM model gave a much smaller loss (RMSE) compared to the FFNN (0.06 vs 0.1). The smaller loss doesn't seem to be due to overfitting, as the losses on the training set and test set are very close.

Question:
So, is it reasonable to use LSTM for this task? Are there any studies or literature supporting the use of LSTM for non-sequential data in regression tasks?

Here is the code for LSTM:

```py
    X_train = tensor([[[ 1.4484,  0.7291,  0.6826,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]],
                      [[-1.1500,  0.4385,  0.8845,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]],
                      [[ 0.2358,  1.3103, -1.1840,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]],
                      ...,
                      [[-1.4964, -0.1426, -1.4673,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]],
                      [[-0.4571, -1.3049, -1.7294,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]],
                      [[ 1.6216, -1.3049, -1.9490,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]]])

    y_train = tensor([[[ 0.5081]],
                      [[ 0.9991]],
                      [[-0.2330]],
                      ...,
                      [[-0.1037]],
                      [[-0.3245]],
                      [[-0.6687]]])

    class LSTMNet(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size=128, num_layers=2):
            super(LSTMNet, self).__init__()
            self.hidden_size = hidden_size
            self.num_layers = num_layers
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
            self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)

        def forward(self, x):
            h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
            c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
            out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
            out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :]) 
            return out

    model = LSTMNet(X_train.shape[2]) 
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    
    model.train()
    for data, target in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! While you're waiting for a response here, you might be interested in having a look to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ that is dedicated to data sciences.